# Customization default UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I want to change default UIAlertView background color for view (gray) to red. How can I do it?

Comment: `UIAlertView` isn't customizable. Find a 3rd party replacement that supports customizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to customize the default UIAlertView. Perhaps, you will need to rollup your own one using UIView or look for the one that suits your requirement from this  [customized alertViews](http://code4app.net/category/alertview)  list.

Maybe, this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AlertView also might help you.